# C# - locking in threads with mixed file and folder usage (thread safety)

Tags: c#, locking, thread-safety

I wanted to ask if there is a special mechanism in C# or .net which can do the following:

I have an multi threading application and I want to prevent threads doing something on the same file/folder. like the `lock(Object obj)` command it should block if an other thread is changing something on this file or folder or a sub folder.

For example:
All threads starting at the same time (ok pseudo same time ;) ).
Thread A: uses folder1\folder2\file.txt and should lock it with an mechanism.
Thread B: uses folder1\file2.txt and should open another lock
Thread C: wants to rename folder1 and should be blocked as long as Thread A and Thread B releases the lock.
Thread D: renames folder3 and opens a lock wich blocks nothing.
Just an example what I'd like to see...

It should be possible to have unlimited hierachical dependencies. I know there are some mechanisms for supporting file locking and maybe there is something to also lock folders with sub folders and prevent parent changes. If there is nothing then I have to implement it on my own.

Comment: I would roll my own solution.

Comment: So, what happens if thread D first renames `folder1` to `folder3`, and then thread A tries to use `folder1\folder2\file.txt`? This does not seem like tasks to be performed in parallell, but rather in sequence. Also, since your threads are competing for access to a single resource (the disk), there is likely little to gain from using threads here.

Comment: Ok... And what mechanism would you use? I don't think the lock() command is the best one for this...

Comment: @ Fredrik Mörk: That's no problem in the real implementation. Maybe I got a bad example but the point is, I need to be able to lock files or folder and it must not be possible to do something in parent folders. By the way: Thread D renames folder3 to anything else just to show that an independent folder shouldn't be influenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my quick implementation of the problem. Feedback welcome.

```
class LockManager
{
    private static Object managerLock = new Object();

    private static Dictionary<string, int> fileLocks = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private static Dictionary<string, int> folderLocks = new Dictionary<string, int>();



    public static void EnterFolderLock(string folderPath)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(managerLock);

        string aLocked;

        // test if all subfolders are not locked
        do
        {
            aLocked = null;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> folderLock in folderLocks)
            {
                // if it is in a locked folder
                if (folderPath.Contains(folderLock.Key))
                {
                    aLocked = folderLock.Key;
                    break;
                }
                else if (folderLock.Key.Contains(folderPath))
                {
                    aLocked = folderLock.Key;
                    break;
                }
            }


            if (aLocked == null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> fileLock in fileLocks)
                {
                    // if it has a locked file
                    if (fileLock.Key.Contains(folderPath))
                    {
                        aLocked = fileLock.Key;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }



            if (aLocked != null)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(managerLock);

                // wait until the lock was released
                Monitor.Enter(aLocked);
                Monitor.Exit(aLocked);

                Monitor.Enter(managerLock);
            }
        } while (aLocked != null);


        if (folderLocks.ContainsKey(folderPath))
        {
            folderLocks[folderPath] = folderLocks[folderPath] + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            folderLocks.Add(folderPath, 1);
        }

        Monitor.Exit(managerLock);

        // get the file lock
        Monitor.Enter(folderPath);

    }


    public static void EnterFileLock(string filePath)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(managerLock);

        string aLockedFolder;

        // test if all subfolders are not locked
        do
        {
            aLockedFolder = null;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> folderLock in folderLocks)
            {
                // if it is in a locked folder
                if (filePath.Contains(folderLock.Key))
                {
                    aLockedFolder = folderLock.Key;
                    break;
                }
            }



            if (aLockedFolder != null)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(managerLock);

                // wait until the lock was released
                Monitor.Enter(aLockedFolder);
                Monitor.Exit(aLockedFolder);

                Monitor.Enter(managerLock);
            }
        } while (aLockedFolder != null);


        if (fileLocks.ContainsKey(filePath))
        {
            fileLocks[filePath] = fileLocks[filePath] + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            fileLocks.Add(filePath, 1);
        }

        Monitor.Exit(managerLock);

        // get the file lock
        Monitor.Enter(filePath);

    }


    public static void ExitFolderLock(string folderPath)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(managerLock);

        if (!folderLocks.ContainsKey(folderPath))
        {
            // key is missing!!!
            throw new Exception("Can't exit this folder lock if it's not open!");
        }
        else if (folderLocks[folderPath] == 0)
        {
            // key is missing!!!
            throw new Exception("Can't exit this folder lock if it's not open! Something strange happened. Please debug.");
        }
        else if (folderLocks[folderPath] == 1)
        {
            // last entry remove
            folderLocks.Remove(folderPath);
        }
        else
        {
            folderLocks[folderPath] = folderLocks[folderPath] - 1;
        }

        Monitor.Exit(folderPath);

        Monitor.Exit(managerLock);
    }


    public static void ExitFileLock(string filePath)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(managerLock);

        if (!fileLocks.ContainsKey(filePath))
        {
            // key is missing!!!
            throw new Exception("Can't exit this file lock if it's not open!");
        }
        else if (fileLocks[filePath] == 0)
        {
            // key is missing!!!
            throw new Exception("Can't exit this file lock if it's not open! Something strange happened. Please debug.");
        }
        else if (fileLocks[filePath] == 1)
        {
            // last entry remove
            fileLocks.Remove(filePath);
        }
        else
        {
            fileLocks[filePath] = fileLocks[filePath] - 1;
        }

        Monitor.Exit(filePath);

        Monitor.Exit(managerLock);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This may sound like magic. But you can actually lock on strings.

```
lock (@"c:\file.txt") {
   // Do something
}
```

The reason is how .Net handles strings internally. Normally any two strings that contains the same data will be a reference to the same object. Alternatively you can just add them to a Dictionary (keys are unique entries) and use the value (object) to lock.

Here is a simple example:

```
Dictionary<string, object> LockObjects = new Dictionary<string, object>();
void DoStuff(string file) {
  // Lock while modifying LockObjects
  string lockObj = null;
  lock (LockObjects) {
    if (!LockObjects.Contains(file))
      LockObjects.Add(file, new Object());
    lockObj = LockObjects[file];
  }
  lock (lockObj) {
    // Do stuff to the file
  }
}
```

`lock ()` will also wait for others to finish, so any thread can safely lock and wait.

In your program logic you MUST make sure you don't open up for deadlock scenarios. For example Thread1 locks File1. Thread2 opens File2. T1 won't continue until it gets a lock on F2. T2 won't continue until it gets a lock on F1. Both will wait forever. This has to be avoided by design!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't a thread come in and modify the dictionary collection while a lock was acquired on lockObj? Could this potentially cause a deadlock situation?

Comment: Modifying the dictionary while "lock (lockObj)" is in use won't affect anything, you already have your file lock object and the method only adds if its missing. If you modify the dictionary from another thread another place altogether them you must make sure to lock it before modifying or you will cause a race condition.

Comment: I should probably had pointed out that using a dynamic string (filename) for locking is not recommended. See more about how .Net treats string and references on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can `lock` while opening and closing a file, and writing your "file lock" data. Threads that run into a locked file, can wait for a signal, for instance:

```
lock(somelock)
{
  while (MyLockedFiles.Contains(thefile))
  {
    // check again as soon as a file closes
    Monitor.Wait(somelock);
  }
  // Open the file
  MyLockedFiles.Add(thefile);
}
```

And when closing the file:

```
lock(somelock)
{
  MyLockedFiles.Remove(thefile);
  // make blocked threads check the MyLockedFiles list
  Monitor.PulseAll(somelock);
}
```

All that in a File I/O wrapper class, so you only open files on one spot.

Comment: By the way, you'd still need to prevent a deadlock: When Process A wants to copy File 1 to File 2, and Process B wants to copy File 2 to File 1, at the exact same time for instance. You'd have to always lock files in the exact same order, ie. alphabetically.